# Divided differences in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am performing that Newton's method for divided differences (the backward version as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences)) but I have problems in this part:

```
for j=1:n
        for i=n:-1:j
            d(i)=(d(i)-d(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-j));   
        end

    end
```

How Can I start doing this process avoiding using d(0)?

I have tried this so far:

```
for j=1:n
    for i=n:-1:j+1
        d(i)=(d(i)-d(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-j)); 

    end

end
```

I hope this helps (I only need someones verification):).

> > Here is the whole code :)

```
 n=15; 
t=-5:5;
 d=zeros(1,n); 
x=linspace(-5,5,n); 
for i=1:n
>     d(i)=1/(1+x(i)^2); 
end
> 
> for j=1:n
>     for i=n:-1:j+1
>         d(i)=(d(i)-d(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-j)); 
>             
>     end
>     end
> 
> 
> disp('The coefficients are:') 
disp(d)
```

> My results

Computing 15 coefficients, the polynomial is the following:

[image]

With 5 coefficients

[image]

> Details

I want to plot the interpolation polynomial, so the real whole code looks like this:

```
n = 15;                    
t = -5:5;
d = zeros(1,n+1);            
x = linspace(-5,5,n+1); 
for i = 1:n+1
     d(i)=1/(1+x(i)^2); 
end

for j = 1:n
    for i = n+1:-1:j+1     
        d(i) = (d(i)-d(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-j)); 
    end
end


disp('The coefficients are:')
disp(d)



x_1=linspace(-5,5,30);
y_1=d(1)+...
    d(2).*(x_1-x(1))+...
    d(3).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2))+...
    d(4).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3))+...
    d(5).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4))+...
    d(6).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5))+...
    d(7).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6))+...
    d(8).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7))+...
    d(9).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7)).*(x_1-x(8))+...
    d(10).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7)).*(x_1-x(8)).*(x_1-x(9))+...
    d(11).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7)).*(x_1-x(8)).*(x_1-x(9)).*(x_1-x(10))+...
    d(12).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7)).*(x_1-x(8)).*(x_1-x(9)).*(x_1-x(10)).*(x_1-(x(11)))+...
    d(13).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7)).*(x_1-x(8)).*(x_1-x(9)).*(x_1-x(10)).*(x_1-(x(11))).*(x_1-x(12))+...
    d(14).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7)).*(x_1-x(8)).*(x_1-x(9)).*(x_1-x(10)).*(x_1-(x(11))).*(x_1-x(12)).*(x_1-x(13))+...
    d(15).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7)).*(x_1-x(8)).*(x_1-x(9)).*(x_1-x(10)).*(x_1-(x(11))).*(x_1-x(12)).*(x_1-x(13)).*(x_1-x(14))+...
    d(16).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)).*(x_1-x(5)).*(x_1-x(6)).*(x_1-x(7)).*(x_1-x(8)).*(x_1-x(9)).*(x_1-x(10)).*(x_1-(x(11))).*(x_1-x(12)).*(x_1-x(13)).*(x_1-x(14)).*(x_1-x(15));    


z_1=1./(1+(x_1).^2);

disp('Our differences are:')
disp(z_1-y_1)
plot(x_1,y_1)
```

but this is extremely ugly, so I want to put the polynomial y_1 in a for loop :)

Comment: I do not see any `d(0)` here!!

Comment: sorry I've edited :)

Comment: Ready :) the other one was wrong :) jajajaja

Comment: So what Can I do? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want that I show you all the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common indexing problem. Simply shifting your index by 1 can solve it. You'll just need to remember that now your d(1) is the old d(0) ( or say, the d(0) you see in math text). The math remains the same, you just index them differently.

```
n = 15;                    
t = -5:5;
d = zeros(1,n+1);          % Give d one more element. The math notation d(0):d(15) will be equivalent to d(1):d(16) here.   
x = linspace(-5,5,n+1); 
for i = 1:n+1
     d(i)=1/(1+x(i)^2); 
end

for j = 1:n
    for i = n+1:-1:j+1     % Also shift i by 1 because you use this to index d.
        d(i) = (d(i)-d(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-j)); 
    end
end
```

This is just an example to show you how to circumvent the indexing problem. You'll have to verify the mathematical validity yourself.

For the last part of your code, you can use recursive function call:

```
function y = ff(ii)
if ii > 0
    y = ff(ii-1) + d(ii+1).*(x_1-x(ii));
else
    y = d(1);
end
end
```

You'll see that when ii = 1:

```
y = ff(1) = ff(0) + d(2).*(x_1-x(1)) = d(1) + d(2).*(x_1-x(1));
```

and when ii = 2:

```
y = ff(2) = ff(1) + d(3).*(x_1-x(2)) = d(1) + d(2).*(x_1-x(1)) + d(3).*(x_1-x(2))
```

and so on...

Comment: It says:  Attempted to access d(16); index out of
bounds because numel(d)=15.

Error in Prblm19four (line 13)
        d(i)=(d(i)-d(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-j));

Comment: You'll have to post how you declare the variable `d` then. But it seems that you originally just have 15 elements. You ran into problem when you tried to access the d(0). Now you shift index by one, and you run into problem with d(16). You seem to need one more element for your `d`.

Comment: Ok, let me just post my algorithm :), just a second please :)

Comment: Ready, I will be back so please don't disconnect :), I only have to go to a conference and I'll be back right ? :)

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, let me check it, and Can I let you know if I have problems?

Comment: Just so you know, I made a small change to the codes. I forgot to loop through 1:n+1 in the `d(i)=1/(1+x(i)^2);` part.

Comment: I am back, I think it worked, I will edited my post to let know the result :), But only one thing, How can I write this in a "for" loop?                               d(1)+d(2).*(x_1-x(1))+d(3).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2))+...
    d(4).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3))+...
    d(5).*(x_1-x(1)).*(x_1-x(2)).*(x_1-x(3)).*(x_1-x(4)); Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You've already hard-coded everything. What do you need a for-loop for? Maybe you'd want to clarify that and add it as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Ok, just let me add that detail, and what do you think about the results?, why does the first figure is so ugly ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer the math question for you, but I've updated my answer. For the 'ugly code', you can tidy it up with recursive function calls.

Comment: Is your problem solved ? If so, please accept the answer. Thanks